# ripple RPC method account_tx 'date' attribute issue

Tags: django, timestamp, unix-timestamp, ripple, cryptocurrency

The Ripple RPC method `account_tx`  retrieves a list of transactions that involved the specified account.

While using `account_tx`  it returns the `date` attribute as

```
- 'date': 580452520
```

i.e. in the Unix date format. The real date is May 25, 1998. But actually the transaction date is 2018 May 25 2018. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Improved the formatting to make a usable question. Your question is still unclear - do you want to change the Unix time to a human-readable date format? Or is your problem that the date returned is 20 years wrong? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Ripple epoch is Jan 1st, 2000.
Source: https://wiki.ripple.com/JSON_format#time

Simply add 946684800 to your timestamp then it will be the UNIX epoch timestamp